# After svn commit, Netbeans 8.2 doesn't update file status

Tags: netbeans, svn

Upon doing

```
svn commit
```

my files still appear blue (changed from current revision) in Netbeans (8.2), Ubuntu 14.0.4.

I have to update file status by doing Team - Show Changes. That triggers the refresh.

Is there a workaround for this?

Can I trigger the netbeans check with bash?

[image]